# IOS JSON - Getting unexpected results in the console

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm new to JSON and trying to loop through my JSON Array like this

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.contentArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", dict);
}
```

But keep getting this type of content instead of the actual dictionary in the console:

```
<Content: 0x7fd9b1037950>
```

Here is my code that I used to Create the array:

```
    // Create a new array to hold the locations
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Get an array of dictionaries with the key "locations"
    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    // Iterate through the array of dictionaries
    for(NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        // Create a new Location object for each one and initialise it with information in the dictionary
        Content *content = [[Content alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];
        // Add the Location object to the array
        [locations addObject: content];
   }
```

Comment: Because that's what is actually in your array.  How are you creating the array?

Comment: Edit the code into your question so it's actually readable.

Comment: And you're getting the expected behaviour, what else you are expecting? You are storing a content object and your getting it.

Comment: Thought I would receive something like this:

Comment: @ldindu {
            "section" : "0",
     "ch1" : "",
     "ch2" : "",
     "description": ""
},

Comment: NO, you won't as you are storing an object which is created out of dictionary.

Comment: @Idindu How can receive output like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two things you can do to achieve the behaviour you wanted.

1. Override the following method in your Content class

   ```
   (NSString *)description;
   ```

   And format and return the string as you wanted when instance of Content is printed using NSLog.
2. Store the dict straightaway in your array without wrapping it around Content object then dictionary will get printed as you've expected.

Comment: I think the OP wanted JSON output, so there are better options than this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use JSONModel: https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel.

It is very simple.